# Edit lambda function inline after creation from cloudformation using deployment package (.zip) in s3 bucket

Tags: python, python-2.7, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, s3-bucket

I manually uploaded a deployment package to a s3 bucket of the same region, and used a cloudformation stack to create a lambda function with the bucket specifictation in the resource properties below:

```
 "Code": {
      "S3Bucket": "s3sourcebucket-yy",
      "S3Key": "double-rek/imageProcessor.zip"
    },
```

The lambda function is created successfully, however i cant edit the function using the console, and instead see note saying "lambda function cannot be edited inline since the file name specified in the handler does not match a file name in your deployment package."  is there a way to allow the console to edit the python file within the zip package?